# How to set Json Result to Hidden Field (C# asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am calling a Web Method using Json and get HTML as a result.
I'm trying to set the value of a hidden field with this HTML and then access this hidden field from
server side but the hidden field value is always empty.
please help.
thanks

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ws/srv.asmx/GetReportResult",
    data: JSON.stringify(prm),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data, status) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $("myHiddenField").val = result;                    
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert(request.statusText);
    }
});
```

Comment: There is no code and no question. We can't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line
`$("myHiddenField").val = result;`

To become
`$("myHiddenField").val(result);`

`Jquery` val is a function, so the parenthesis will fix the assignment.

Comment: thanks, but still not working. during post back the hidden field is empty.

Comment: Are you using an is our class to identify the hidden field? Next I would check you jquery selector so it is #myHiddenField for the id or .myHiddenField for class. Of the selector is fine, please post some more code. You may also pull up fiddler to make sure your service is being called and returns the value you expect. Finally you mentioned the service is returning HTML, but you are parsing json in your response. Is that the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

are you have a hidden field control on server side? Than maybe your hidden field id is not myHiddenField when rendered to the page. Check your hidden field on browser and make sure its id is myHiddenField.

if it something like ct100_ct1242_myhiddenField than you can change

```
$("#myHiddenField").val = result;
```

with

```
$("[id$='myHiddenField']").val = result;
```

and if there is no codes changing the hidden field value on page load , page init etc you should see the result.